# GTM Element Visibility trigger with div style changes

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a website with an image carousel that lets users scroll through a set of images, each appearing one at a time.

I am trying to setup an element visibility trigger in Google Tag Manager that fires every time an image appears on screen.

The site code looks like this:

```
<div class="c-carousel__slides row no-gutters" style="transform: translateX(-608px);")>
     <div class="col-12 c-carousel__slide">
          <div class="picture-loading c-card__pack">
               <picture>
               <img alt="alt" src="https://image1.jpg">
     <div class="col-12 c-carousel__slide">
          <div class="picture-loading c-card__pack">
               <picture>
               <img alt="alt" src="https://image2.jpg">
```

In Tag Manager, I can easily create a element visibility trigger, however it relies on observing DOM changes. My website HTML however, doesn't have DOM changes when user's scroll through the images - only the style element changes from 0px (starting value), to -608px, -912px, -1216px and -1520px.

With JS, I can pretty easily grab these values:

```
var z = document.getElementsByClassName('c-carousel__slides row no-gutters')[0].style.transform
```

But I am not sure how that translates into the element visibility trigger in Tag Manager:

[image]

Comment: if I change the Element Selector to .picture-loading.c-card__pack the trigger fires each time a new image appears. However, I then need to build a variable that grabs the current image in the carousel. I can specific which element in an array like so: var z = document.getElementsByClassName('col-12 c-carousel__slide')[2] but how to detect which image is currently being shown by the carousel?

Comment: Well looks like you've solved it. You already mentioned how the shown image is different from the hidden. You mentioned the style element changes. Just iterate through this array and check the styles.

Comment: But how do I iterate through the array?

Comment: This is your guy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find